# Ubuntu 22.04 VNC remote access password check failed, how to fix from terminal

Tags: server, ssh, password, remote-desktop, vnc

so I am using both putty and VNC viewer to remotely access Raspberry PI 4 from my pc, I set everything needed for VNC viewer, the issue is that each time I boot the RPI the VNC password changes and now I can't access it anymore.

currently I can only access the RPI via Putty, how can I fix that issue from terminal ?